# C UNIX Shell execvp Echoing Quotes

Tags: c, shell, unix, exec, echo

So I'm programming a basic UNIX minishell in C. Everything has been going smoothly, however I recently redid the way it parses arguments from the original string it gets from the console. Here's an example of the way it parses:

```
$> echo HELLO "" WORLD!
HELLO "" WORLD!
```

The argument array looks like this: [echo0, HELLO0, ""0, WORLD!0]

I pass it like so:

```
execvp(args[0], args);
```

However, echo is supposed to omit quotes, and as you can see it prints them out. Since echo isn't a builtin command in my case, I can't customize the way it prints. Does anybody know why this might be happening? I want to omit double quotes, but include every other sort of character(besides null of course). However the empty string counts as an argument itself, so:

```
echo HELLO "" WORLD!
```

should output:

```
HELLO  WORLD!
```

with 2 spaces in between, not:

```
HELLO WORLD!
```

with just one (since an empty string is an argument).

I hope this isn't too confusing. If you guys need any clarification, please just ask; I'd be happy to post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shell that strips quotes when parsing the command line. If you pass them to `exec*` call directly, echo echoes them. It's then equivalent to `echo HELLO '""' WORLD!`.

Comment: Hmm, so I need to strip the quotes myself before passing it to exec*?

Comment: What about in the case of an empty string? How do I represent that?

Comment: @Scriptonaut Using your example: `[echo0, HELLO0, 0, WORLD!0]`.

Comment: So do I have to explicitly detect if I'm dealing with an empty string, or is there a general way to deal with the quotes inside my iterating loop?

Comment: Well, the point why shell strips quotes is because they have meaning — combining space separated arguments in one, handling of variable expansion, passing empty argument, etc. If you want the same effect — you should parse quotes to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/echo` doesn't know about quotes. It simply prints all the arguments separated by spaces. The reason what you said works with a shell, is that the shell knows about quotes and passes an empty string as the second argument.

Comment: So then how do I represent an empty string? I can't insert null for every quote, and I can't use memmove for every quote because there are a few cases in which I need one of my args to be nothing at all.

Comment: @Scriptonaut You need to do a proper job of parsing the quotes. That requires at least a finite state machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *args1[] = { "/bin/echo", "HELLO", "\"\"", "WORLD!", 0 };
    char *args2[] = { "/bin/echo", "HELLO", "",     "WORLD!", 0 };
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        execvp(args1[0], args1);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (wait(0) > 0)
        ;
    execvp(args2[0], args2);
    return(1);
}
```

This demonstrates the difference.  There's no shell to interpret I/O redirection etc when you use `execvp()` — although in this case, `execv()` would do as well since I've specified the path for the `echo` command.

Comment: So how exactly do I omit quotes without inserting a null character?

For example, 

    echo HELLO"        "WORLD!

Is two arguments, echo, and the rest. If I inserted a null character for each quote it would appear as three arguments.

Comment: Actually, it's not just "would do" — specifying path makes the use of `execvp` pointless and the thing will fail if, for whatever reason, `echo` is only available as `/usr/bin/echo` for example. (Not that it is related in any way to the question).

Comment: C'mon, @Scriptonaut, it's your code, how can we tell you how your input should be interpreted? Use `system` if you want it to work exactly as if it's run using shell.

Comment: @Scriptonaut: the `args2` array shows how to represent an empty argument in C.  Did you try the code?  Did you observe its output?  Did you try to work out why it's written as it is?  Note that an empty string is different from a null pointer; a null pointer would be incorrect.  (And yes, it is confusing that the empty string in C is represented by adjacent double quotes.)